# How to use a second (minute or hour is to long for immediate response) based trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing an immediate response code in google script which must monitor inbox at current time and if it detects a new e-mail with given subject then it runs the code and replies to the e-mail and at the end it marks the e-mail as read.

The whole stuff works fine, however I want it to get started more frequently than once in a minute. Thus I guess I can't use trigger option from the scripts interface. Will it work if I won't specify a trigger? How can I organize all this? I am using this stuff with google free quota for my personal use only.

thanks beforehand

Comment: I believe every minute is the finest granularity you can get. What's wrong with every 60 seconds, may I ask?

Comment: Have a look at IFTTT , it's a free service that provides many ways to do things when anything happens ( the name comes from "if this then that...") and is really simple to use :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its not advisable to do what you want because you will run out of quota.
But its possible. Not with triggers as they run at most once a minute.
If you must, write a htmlservice app with a setInterval. Call a server method to do your work. Leave the webapp open all day.